# Possible to invoke the Start menu without Explorer.exe?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have read that in recent versions of Windows, the Start menu is a separate process. In deed, I see "Start" in the Task Manager. So, if I create my own shell and replace the "explorer.exe" with my application in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`, is there a way to invoke the Start menu, as if I clicked the Windows button on the Taskbar?

---

**Reason for request of reopening**

The linked existing answers were pressing the Windows key or sending the Ctrl+Esc shortcut to open the Start Menu. That only works when the "explorer.exe" is the default shell. Those keys DO NOT WORK when the shell is something else. To test it, change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` from "explorer.exe" to something else like "notepad.exe", log out, log in, and then press such keys. It does not show the Start menu.

Comment: I don't have access to any Windows 10 system right now, but have you tried [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) with `SC_TASKLIST`?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I have created a default Windows application project in Visual C++, and added `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_TASKLIST, 0);` (I was not sure what the handle should be, so I just used the application's window handle) under `case IDM_ABOUT` so that clicking the "About" in the main menu will execute the line. It worked only when `explorer.exe` is running. That is, if the shell is something else, it had no effect. Now I think that the answer to my original question is probably "NO", that is, without `explorer.exe`, no Start menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a user logs in, the explorer process is created by `userinit` process. `Userinit` performs some initialization of the user environment (such as running the login script and applying group policies) and then looks in the registry at the Shell value and creates a process to run the system-defined shell – by default, `Explorer.exe`. Then Userinit exits. This is why `Explorer.exe` is shown by various process explorers with no parent – its parent has exited.

Because windows uses `Explorer.exe` to start startup processes,all normal processes are children of `Explorer.exe`,unless a child was dead and child's child didn't.

The startmenu is also a child of explorer.If you don't run it, the Start menu will not work properly.